# AJAX post a modelview to my controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm making a website where a moderator can at a certain pc part. This is just a form on my website. I want the form to post trough AJAX so it doesn't refreshed after a part has been added. I'm making the application with ASP.net Core 2.0

**This is my view:**

```
    @model PcBuildAddViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add";
}
<div class="form-container">
    <form id="AddPcForm" class="form-wrapper" method="post">
        <p>Name:</p>
        <input asp-for="@Model.PcPart._Name" type="text" class="form-control"/>
        <br/>
        <p >Type:</p>
        <div class="form-select">
            <select asp-for="@Model.PcPart._Type" asp-items="@Model.AllTypes">
            </select>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <p>Info:</p>
        <input asp-for="@Model.PcPart.Information" type="text" class="form-control"/>
        <br/>
        <p>Properties:</p>
        <div class="form-select">
            <select asp-for="@Model.Properties" asp-items="@Model.AllProperties" multiple="multiple">
            </select>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <p>Image:</p>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Image" type="file" class="inputfile inputfile-1"/>
        <label asp-for="@Model.Image">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17">
            </svg> <span>Choose a file&hellip;</span>
        </label>
        <br/>
        <button class="btn btn-1 btn-1e" type="submit">
            <span>Add</span>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**My viewmodel that i want to post trough AJAX:**

```
public class PcBuildAddViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> AllProperties { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>();
    public List<SelectListItem> AllTypes { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>();
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
    public PcPart PcPart { get; set; }
    public List<int> Properties { get; set; }

    public PcBuildAddViewModel()
    {
    }

    public PcBuildAddViewModel(List<Propertie> allProperties, List<string> allTypes)
    {            
        foreach (string type in allTypes)
        {
            SelectListItem listItem = new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = type,
                Value = type
            };
            AllTypes.Add(listItem);
        }

        foreach (Propertie propertie in allProperties)
        {
            SelectListItem listItem = new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = propertie._Value,
                Value = propertie.Id.ToString()
            };
            AllProperties.Add(listItem);
        }
    }
}
```

**My Action Post method where I want to receive the form:**

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddPcPart(PcBuildAddViewModel viewModel) 
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Add");
        }
```

**And finnaly my AJAX:**

```
$('#AddPcForm').on('submit', function(event) {

        var viewModel = $(this).serialize();


        ajaxPost("/PCBuild/AddPcPart", viewModel);

        event.preventDefault();
    });
function ajaxPost(ul, dt) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ul,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: dt,
            success: ajaxSucces,
            error: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

I hope that someone can help me. I've tried this without AJAX and it worked fine but when I call trough AJAX. I get a empty viewmodel or when I put [Frombody] in front of my parameter in the controller i get a null viewmodel.

Comment: Remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` option (when you use `.serialize()` it need to be the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`)

Comment: also try calling event.preventdefault before ajax call you can never be sure how much time will that take to reach the code since its an ajax call

Comment: Well, you can keep posting as JSON if you like, but you need to prefix your action param with `[FromBody]`.

Comment: why u don't try with @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PcPart._Name) , etc.. then u are sure of the binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stephen Muecke that posted the answer. The problem is that the contentType needs to be the default so I just removed the contentType parameter in my AJAX post. After that I removed the [FromBody] because that wasn't needed anymore.